# Thinning lemma in simply typed lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

From "Type Theory and Formal Proof" by Rob Nederpelt and Herman Geuvers:

> Definition 2.4.2
>
> (1) A statement is of the form $M : \alpha$, where $M \in
>  \Lambda_{\mathbb{T}}$ and $\sigma \in \mathbb{T}$. In such a
>   statement, $M$ is called the subject and $\alpha$ the type.
>
> (2) A declaration is a statement with a variable as subject.
>
> (3) A context is a list of declarations with different subjects.
>
> Definition 2.4.5 (Derivation rules for $\lambda \to$)
>
> (var) $\Gamma \vdash x : \alpha$ if $x : \alpha \in \Gamma$
>
> (appl) $\Gamma \vdash M : \alpha \to \tau \quad \Gamma \vdash N
>  : \alpha \implies \Gamma \vdash M N : \tau$
>
> (abst) $\Gamma, x : \alpha \vdash M : \tau \implies \Gamma \vdash
>  \lambda x : \alpha . M : \alpha \to \tau$
>
> Definition 2.10.1
>
> (2) Context $\Gamma'$ is a subcontext of context $\Gamma$, or $\Gamma'
>  \subseteq \Gamma$, if all declarations occurring in $\Gamma'$ also
>   occur in $\Gamma$, in the same order.
>
> Lemma 2.10.5
>
> (1) (Thinning) Let $\Gamma'$ and $\Gamma''$ be contexts such that
>   $\Gamma' \subseteq \Gamma''$. If $\Gamma' \vdash M : \alpha$, then
>   also $\Gamma'' \vdash M : \alpha$.

Note: I replaced the horizontal bar between the premisses and conclusion in the derivation rules with $\implies$ since I could not get the bar to typeset as intended.

Suppose I assign the following in Lemma 2.10.5:

$\Gamma' = y : B$

$\Gamma'' = x : C, y : B$

$M = \lambda x : A . y$

$\alpha = A \to B$

Then

$\Gamma' \vdash M : \alpha = y : B \vdash \lambda x : A . y : A \to B$

$\Gamma'' \vdash M : \alpha = x : C, y : B \vdash \lambda x : A . y : A \to B$.

For a derivation of the first I have:

(i) $y : B, x : A \vdash y : B$ (var)

(ii) $y : B \vdash \lambda x : A . y : A \to B$ (abst on i)

I am unable to find a derivation for the second as the lemma implies. Is there a derivation, or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1):

This may just be a consequence of `Convention 1.7.2 From now on, we identify α-convertible λ-terms.`